# Pandas Dataframe find intervals for a value and attribute name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, intervals

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe given by:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 4)),
columns ['value', 'a', 'b', 'c']) 
df2['low'] = ''
df2
      value  a  b  c  low
   0      5  3  7  9    
   1      9  3  7  9    
   2      2  5  0  8    
   3      2  8  2  7    
   4      5  5  7  7
```

I need to get the letter of the interval where my value is in the column low.

For example for the first lign where value = 5.
I want to indentify that value is between "a" and "b" and attribute the letter "a" in the column low.

If value < a < b < c then low = 'None'
If value >a or >b or >c then low = Max (a;b;c)

Output expected :

```
   value  a  b  c  low
0      5  3  7  9   a    
1      9  3  7  9   c 
2      2  5  0  8   b 
3      2  8  2  7   b 
4      5  5  7  7   a
```

I came with the following but not really sure how to increment the frame with that:

```
if min(a, b, c)<x<max(a,b,c):
    print(min(a,b,c))
else:
    if x<min(a,b,c) :
        print('None')
    else:
        print(max(a,b,c))
```

Any suggestion to do it in an efficient way?

Comment: Add that to your question, so show an expected output dataframe.  That helps greatly.  Thank you.

Comment: Hi Scott. Thanks for your feedback I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 4), columns=list('ABCD'))

# Copy first dataframe and calculate distance from A column values
df2 = df.copy()
df2['B'] = abs(df2['A']-df2['B'])
df2['C'] = abs(df2['A']-df2['C'])
df2['D'] = abs(df2['A']-df2['D'])

# Delete first column
df2.drop(['A'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Find from copied dataframe the lowest value and insert name of that value
# into original dataframe
df['E'] = df2.idxmin(axis=1)
```